# 幾人も or 一杯? Kanji or hiragana?

Tags: kanji, politeness, counters, idioms

I am writing the following sentence:

サン・パウロに日本人がいっぱいいるから。。。よかったですね！

And I'd like to know if 幾人も could be a more respectful/more natural replacement for 一杯, and whether I should be using kanji.

Comment: I am writing of how I've been able to speak Japanese outside of Japan. After telling of an experience meeting Japanese people in a marathon, and I'd like to continue:
"It's because there are plenty of Japanese people in São Paulo—hooray!"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> 「サン・パウロ**に**日本人がいっぱいいるから。。。よかったですね！」

This sentence is OK.  The only thing I would change to make it more natural would be the 「に」.  Using 「には」 would make it far more natural.

> And I'd like to know if 幾人{いくにん}も could be a more respectful/more natural replacement for 一杯{いっぱい}, and whether I should be using kanji.

Using 「幾人も」 in this context would be a bad idea.  Why?  Because it only means "many" mostly when the number is a dozen or two ***at the most***.  São Paulo has about a million Japanese and Japanese Brazilians, correct?  That is definitely ***way*** too many to call 幾人も.

I would not worry about writing 「いっぱい」 using kanji.  Your sentence is already very informal with the use of 「から」 and 「よかったですね！」.  「から」 is more informal than many J-learners seem to think.

Answer (score 1):

幾人も isn't a more respectful/more natural replacement for 一杯 and it is a very literary word, so we rarely say it in conversation.

You can put いっぱい into たくさん, かなり, 大勢. いっぱい written in hiragana is more common than the one written in kanji.

Comment: How would you rank these in terms of enthusiasm and respect? I am using distal style, but in the most relaxed manner possible. I just used 沢山 in a previous sentence, so I'd avoid it (in Kanji, because of one of my recipients is a friend who likes to use it like that).

Comment: There isn't respectful form of these words. It is difficult to use these words differently because they are almost the same meaning. As my personal opinion,  I think 大勢, たくさん, かなり, いっぱい is the  descending order of stiff.